# Ошибка Connection reset протокол SMTP

Tags: java, сеть, сокет, smtp

Есть простой SMTP клиент, который лишь должен отправлять команды на сервер SMTP и получать код ответа и сообщение. Все бы ничего, но по какой-то причине дальше команды STARTTLS клиент отказывается работать с ошибкой Connection reset. В чем может быть ошибка? Привожу ниже код:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class EmailClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        int port = 587;
        String from = "your_email@example.com";
        String to = "recipient@example.com";
        String subject = "Test email";
        String body = "This is a test email.";

        try {
            // Create a socket connection to the mail server
            Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

            // Read the server's greeting
            String response = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(response);

            // Send the EHLO command to initiate the SMTP conversation
            out.println("EHLO " + host);
            out.flush();

            do {
                response = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(response);

            }while (!Objects.equals(response, "250 SMTPUTF8"));

            // Start a secure TLS connection
            out.println("STARTTLS");
            out.flush();
            response = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(response);

            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(socket, host, port, true);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sslSocket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sslSocket.getOutputStream()));


            // Set the sender and recipient of the email
            out.println("MAIL FROM:<" + from + ">");
            out.flush();
            response = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(response);

            out.println("RCPT TO:<" + to + ">");
            out.flush();
            response = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(response);

            // Send the email content
            out.println("DATA");
            out.flush();
            response = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(response);

            out.println("Subject:" + subject);
            out.println("");
            out.println(body);
            out.println(".");
            out.flush();
            response = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(response);

            // Close the connection
            out.println("QUIT");
            out.flush();
            response = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(response);

            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас порт указан 25. Смените порт с 25 на 587.

`int port = 587`;

Исходящий SMTP-сервер smtp.gmail.com поддерживает TLS. Если ваш клиент начинается с простого текста, перед выполнением команды STARTTLS используйте порт 465 (для SSL) или порт 587 (для TLS).

```
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\xxx>telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
Connecting To smtp.gmail.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed

C:\Users\xxx>telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$ openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -crlf
CONNECTED(000001A0)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = smtp.gmail.com
   i:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
 1 s:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
   i:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
 2 s:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
   i:C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEiTCCA3GgAwIBAgIRALtoYgdHbzujCqo/4U31j6wwDQYJ
OFZEIuFvOgPE1R6GtZSjDT5GgTHP+1ffkdBBlQJYd/jICN8IajGUykfhlnkthxRo
Qjf7D7BM3XWKSsi2u3Z4+NIxxg8CX9R3k0GbxNZxQqjIvypsWSW+X1/9O0XAS67r
RyLOz/nExZIzNpgDBaqK6UC1oY4iOQz6V57R315RNUSGvtiNGMq5QvJyl1l9IyLP
QxynB1E/NpyNhZ4sWA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = smtp.gmail.com

issuer=C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: ECDSA
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4583 bytes and written 429 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: При замене порта 25 на 587 ошибка, к сожалению, не пропадает. На строчке line = reader.readLine(); возникает Exception и программа вываливается

Comment: 1. Попробуйте 465. 2. Проверьте telnet smtp.gmail.com telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 и telnet smtp.gmail.com 465 с вашего сервера/компютера - может, у вас порты закрыты. 3. Что за Exception и где - readLine у вас несколько. Вы хоть детали писали бы.

Comment: Порты проверил. Если бы они были закрыты, не получал бы ответа при посылке команд STARTTLS, EHLO. Получаем зависание на readLine после попытки получить ответ после MAIL TO команды